# How to include plain text file in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

I am using emacs org-mode with taskjuggler export. I like to include multiple org files into one main org-file and export all content into one taskjuggler file, so I can seperate e.g. sources from projects.

I thought about using the #+INCLUDE: macro, but this one includes additional header information like the source filename. I was able to remove author and timestamp by customizing the export, but I can not get rid of the filename.

Question: what would be a good solution to include org-files so I can use them with taskjuggler export?

Comment: When I use include `#+INCLUDE` in Org-mode 7.6 it does not include any file name for the included file.

Comment: How did you do your export? When export it using C-c C-e U I do get included the file name without extension underlined by equal-signs.
I try directly to export it using taskjuggler it tells me no task specified.

Comment: Has `C-c C-e J` worked in the past for taskjuggler export?  I haven't used it but googling for TJ export from org I get: http://orgmode.org/manual/TaskJuggler-export.html which shows you need specific tags for taskjuggler to be able to export, otherwise you get that particular error.

Answer (score 3):

The title of your question is a bit conflicting with the text of the question.

If you are wanting to include plain text, you could try something like this:

```
#+begin_src sh :exports results :results output                                 
  cat your_file.txt                                     
#+end_src
```

I've used this in the past to add the contents of a file to a web page via HTML export.  The results of executing the `src` block are, in this case, set in a ` block in HTML.  Not sure what TaskJuggler does.

You can also do this with the `#+include` macro: http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html  If you want to include certain parts of the `#+include`'d file, use the `:lines` parameter as outlined in the link above.

Comment: I tried both suggestions. The first does not apply to simple ascii export. The second one works with :lines similar to without.
I tried the body only attribute, but still it is including extra formating.
I thought about writing a simple batch script which concatenates the files of desire and invoke the export-as-taskjuggerler function from within, but I have no idea to do so either

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but fits under the title for anyone that ends up here.

I modified @cm2 's answer to use `pygmentize` vs `cat`, then used `display-ansi-colors` to remove the ANSI color codes. eg:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :results raw
pygmentize Test.java
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
public class Test {    
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
String result = "hello";
    System.out.print(result);
  }
}
```